# Log4j2 logs are in different patterns

Tags: log4j2

In our project we have multiple modules. Rest module will call another module say M1. Rest is using Log4j1 and module M1 upgraded to Log4j2 2.13.1. Interesting part is all the logs in rest module displaying in one format and other module(when rest called) logs are displayed in different format as below.

Rest module displays logs as below.

INFO | rest controller 1
INFO | rest service layer

Other module shows different format as below. Not sure why it is showing this format. Both are logged in rest log file with differnet formats. is this the default format?

2020-03-29 23:34:54.316  INFO 18602 --- [container1] c.t.v.c.a.Handler : Wating for the result

Answer (score 0):

So your REST module is using Log4j 1 with a configuration file. Your M1 modules is using Log4j 2 with a different configuration file. Log4j 1 and Log4j 2 will not be sharing the same configuration file as they use different configuration syntax. However, it seems both are configured to write to the same file.

You should replace your log4j 1.x jar with the log4j-1.2-api jar from Log4j 2. This will cause the module using log4j 1.x to use Log4j 2 instead and everything will log with the same format.